# Python: Take the Log of all elements in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

I wish to take the logarithm of all elements within the array.
The following code works but it's a bit clunky

```
>>> from math import log10 
>>> logArr = np.empty((3,3))
>>> for i in range(3):
...     for j in range(3):
...             logArr[i][j] = log10(arr[i][j])
... 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.30103   ,  0.47712125],
       [ 0.60205999,  0.69897   ,  0.77815125],
       [ 0.84509804,  0.90308999,  0.95424251]])
```

Does there exist a more efficient/'pythonic' way of doing such an operation?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a numpy function for that, try [numpy.log](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html)

```
>>> arr = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))
>>> np.log(arr)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.69314718,  1.09861229],
       [ 1.38629436,  1.60943791,  1.79175947],
       [ 1.94591015,  2.07944154,  2.19722458]])
```

Or like in your implementation, you can use [numpyp.log10](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html#numpy.log10) to find the logs in base 10.

```
>>> np.log10(arr)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.30103   ,  0.47712125],
       [ 0.60205999,  0.69897   ,  0.77815125],
       [ 0.84509804,  0.90308999,  0.95424251]])
```